# RCpp: expecting a single value error

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to build a package with a function performing a simple convolution using RCpp. The code looks like

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector conv_filter(NumericVector x, NumericVector c){
  int T = x.size();
  int M = (c.size()-1)/2;
  int t, i;    
    NumericVector fx(T);
  for(t=0; t<T; t++){
        for(i=-M; i<M+1; i++){
            if(t+i>=0 && t+i<T){
        fx(t) += c(M+i)*x(t+i);
            }
        }       
    }
    return fx;
}
```

which works fine when sourced, but when built into a package, I keep getting the errors saying "expecting a single value". I guess I have committed very basic mistakes but I cannot see where it comes from even after reading relevant topics. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program works for me:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/hrcho.cpp")

R> conv_filter(1:4, 4:1)
[1]  7 16 25 24
R>
```

using this (just indented) source code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector conv_filter(NumericVector x, NumericVector c){
  int T = x.size();
  int M = (c.size()-1)/2;
  int t, i;    
  NumericVector fx(T);
  for(t=0; t<T; t++){
    for(i=-M; i<M+1; i++){
      if(t+i>=0 && t+i<T){
        fx(t) += c(M+i)*x(t+i);
      }
    }       
  }
  return fx;
}

/*** R
conv_filter(1:4, 4:1)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes when I sourced it, it worked fine too but when packaged, the error about a single value was thrown. The indention was off when I copied the code probably.. thanks for having a look.